# Boole Cut Surface Material

Tags: modeling, animation, materials, modifiers

I have a Boole, which I don't plan to commit, so that it can be animated.  I'd like the cut surface to be a different color than the object that I'm cutting.  Is there a way to do this, or maybe a plug-in that achieves this result?

I'm using 2.8, btw.

Thanks!

Comment: if you use a Solidify you can determine what are the colors of the inside/outside (Material Index Offset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question to be interesting so I did some research on it.

What I found out is that you need to add slots for all materials to the main object. The cutting objects will assign material IDs for its material to the cut out faces.

In the scene below I have created a green cube and a red cube that cuts from the blue cube.

I didn't know this. Neat!

[image]